# Ограничение доступа в интернет

Tags: сеть, wifi, роутер

Есть wifi-роутер с подключением к интернету, к роутеру подключены два свича и сервер, локалка настроена, всё работает. Как сделать так, чтобы компьютеры подключенные по wifi имели доступ только к интернету.

Comment: Что за модель роутера, версия прошивки?Теоретически их можно изолировать создав две подсети 192.168.0.0/24 для беспроводных и 192.168.1.0/24 для проводных.

Comment: @ArcherGodson tp-link номер и прошивку, только завтра узнаю, где можно подробней про создание подсетей узнать?

Comment: Начать можно с этого [Маршрутизация][1] и [Таблица маршрутизации][2]  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F  [2]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может на уровне роутера запретить?)Фаервол+документация по конкретной его версии в руки)

Comment: да, запрещать следует на рутере, но наиболее правильно это сделать при делении на подсети. Т.е. делим сеть на две: wi-fi и провод, в этом случае, посеть wi-fi будет иметь доступ к инету и локальным ресурсам подсети wi-fi. ЕСЛИ рутер позволит так тонко настроить подсеть, то можно запретить и локальные ресурсы подсети wi-fi.